# Same png image file displayed in different locations on screen loses definition - Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

In our Silverlight 5 app we have a 16x16 png that is used on a button within an a custom control to navigate to the page associated with that piece of data. So on some screens there are say six different instances of this control. For some reason although every control is styled identically, on some images the control appears clear, while on others it is blurry. 
Generally it seems as if the controls towards the top of the screen render clearly, while those from the centre and below are blurry. this may or not have any relevance...

I'm stumped as to why this is occuring and what to do about it. Almost every possible thing I find relates to WPF, which has a few more options available.  It's not just this control that it's occuring on but this one is the most widely used and obvious instance:

```
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#D8FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#C6FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#8CFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#3FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="3" Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
          <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Margin="1">
            <Border Opacity="0"  x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" >
              <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                  <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
          </Grid>
        </Border>

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**EDIT: - Now fixed as below**
Fixed after following the link suggested by Franck.

modified it to swallow errors...rather it did that and have blurry images than have the app failing as it did in some circumstances...

```
namespace PixelSnapper
```

{
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Media;

```
public enum PixelSnapType
{
    None, // No snapping
    Closest, // Snap to closest pixel using Math.Round
    TopLeft // Snap to integral portion of pixel by casting to int
}

public class Snapper : UserControl
{
    public Snapper()
    {
        LayoutUpdated += SnapperLayoutUpdated;
        Snap = PixelSnapType.Closest;
    }

    public PixelSnapType Snap { get; set; }

    private void SnapperLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Content == null) return;

        if (Snap == PixelSnapType.None)
        {
            Content.RenderTransform = null;
            return;
        }

        try
        {


            // Remove existing transform so that it is not a part of the calculations
            if (this.transform != null)
            {
                this.transform.X = 0;
                this.transform.Y = 0;
            }

            // Calculate actual location
            var globalTransform = Content.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual) as MatrixTransform;
                if (globalTransform == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

            var p = globalTransform.Matrix.Transform(Zero);

            double deltaX = Snap == PixelSnapType.Closest ? Math.Round(p.X) - p.X : (int)p.X - p.X;
            double deltaY = Snap == PixelSnapType.Closest ? Math.Round(p.Y) - p.Y : (int)p.Y - p.Y;

            // Set new transform
            if (deltaX != 0 || deltaY != 0)
            {

                if (this.transform == null)
                {
                    this.transform = new TranslateTransform();
                    Content.RenderTransform = this.transform;
                }

                if (deltaX != 0)
                {
                    this.transform.X = deltaX;
                }

                if (deltaY != 0)
                {
                    this.transform.Y = deltaY;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }

    }

    private TranslateTransform transform;
    private static readonly Point Zero = new Point(0, 0);

}
```

}

Original courtesy of Dave Relyea: [pixel Snapper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/05/26/pixel-snapping-the-snapper-element.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` on the image otherwise some image WILL be 17x16, 17x17 and 16x17

You might also want to play with quality with this

```
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
```

Comment: I've wanted to - but unfortunately as far as I can tell that's specific to WPF rather than silverlight - I'd tagged the post silverlight but will edit the title to make it clearer. I've used UseLayoutRounding=True (which is silverlight compatible sort of equivalent) but still no joy

Comment: you can use a snap to device pixel class that was made specialy for silverlight you can find it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/05/26/pixel-snapping-the-snapper-element.aspx)

Comment: Marked as answer for the comment with link to Dave Relyea's blog and the pixel snapper class. Worked a charm after a bit of exception handling...Thanks!